# Error: setting an array with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

# constants
n=1000                  # number of time steps to simulate
m=90                    # number of angles
rho=1.225               # kg/m^3
g=-9.8                  # m/s^2
start=0.0               # seconds
end=10                  # seconds
initial_velocity=70     # meters/second
initial_height=5

# object
A=.8            # surface area m^2
C=1.4           # drag coefficient
mass=65         # mass of object in kg

# parameters of simulation
angles=np.array([i for i in range(1,m+1)])
radians=np.radians(angles)

#initalize state variables
t=np.linspace(start,end,n+1)
vx=np.zeros((m,n+1),dtype=np.float64)
vy=np.zeros((m,n+1),dtype=np.float64)
x=np.zeros((m,n+1),dtype=np.float64)
y=np.zeros((m,n+1),dtype=np.float64)

for i in range(m):
        y[i][0]=initial_height
        vx[i][0]=initial_velocity*np.cos(radians[i])
        vy[i][0]=initial_velocity*np.sin(radians[i])

# begin simulation
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        if y[i,j-1]<=0:
            vx[i,j]=0
            vy[i,j]=0
            y[i,j]=0
            x[i,j]=x[i,j-1]
        else:
            # the following code is _corrected_ from the wrong math
            v = np.sqrt( vx[ j-1 ]**2 + vy[ j-1 ]**2 )
            ax = -( 0.5*rho*C*A/mass ) * v**2 * ( vx[ j-1 ] / v )
            ay = g - ( 0.5*rho*C*A/mass ) * v**2 * ( vy[ j-1 ] / v )
            dt=t[j]-t[j-1]
            vx[i,j]=vx[i,j-1]+ax*dt
            vy[i,j]=vy[i,j-1]+ay*dt
            x[i,j]=x[i,j-1]+vx[i,j]*dt
            y[i,j]=y[i,j-1]+vy[i,j]*dt
            if y[i,j]<=0:
                y[i,j]=0
                x[i,j]=x[i,j-1]
                vx[i,j]=0
                vy[i,j]=0

best_distance=0
best_angle=0
for i in range(m):
    if x[i,-1]>best_distance:
        best_distance=x[i,-1]
        best_angle=i+1
```

The problem is I am trying to calculate the speed now using the acceleration and the previous speed with an interval of dt. Since all the expressions are all numbers about vx[i,j] what's the problem here? Please help! vx and vy are all 2-D arrays that store some data, so to calculate the real speed including drag. I introduced the v to simulate better about the projection.

Comment: Well, what is the problem here? What result do you get?

Comment: `angles=np.array([i for i in range(1,m+1)])` can be better phrased as `angles=np.arange(1, m+1)`. You might need to add `, dtype=np.int` to the args for identical behavior. If you need to use `np.array` for some reason, at least replace the comprehension `[i for i in range(1,m+1)]` with just `list(range(1, m + 1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running your code to see your error, at the point where I get the error you mention:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2458d409946f> in <module>()
     46             ay = g - ( 0.5*rho*C*A/mass ) * v**2 * ( vy[ j-1 ] / v )
     47             dt=t[j]-t[j-1]
---> 48             vx[i,j]=vx[i,j-1]+ax*dt
     49             vy[i,j]=vy[i,j-1]+ay*dt
     50             x[i,j]=x[i,j-1]+vx[i,j]*dt

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`ax` is a numpy array:

```
array([-51.70596988,          nan,          nan, ...,          nan,
                nan,          nan])
```

So when you add and multiply it by a scalar, you still get an array, which you then try to assign to `vx[i,j]`, which is a single element (aka, you can't assign a vector to it). That said, I'm also seeing a bunch of `nan`'s in `ax`, so something else is probably wrong, and this code's logic needs debugging.

Comment: Thank you, I found that the vx and vy are actually 2D array, need an extra i for index